# How to send a desktop notification in KDE from a daemon

Tags: linux, notifications, kde4

I have a daemon (`netplugd`) which can take some actions when my cable is being plugged in or out. These actions can be defined via a `bash` script. How can I send a notification (as a different user) to my desktop (using `bash`) that will inform me about the state of the cable.

I have tried the following:

`notify-send` and `knotify --passivepopup` but the daemon shows that `$DISPLAY` is not set.

Comment: little hacky, but if you know what your display should be you can set it, e.g. system("export DISPLAY=:0.0; notify-send \"Hello World\""). $DISPLAY is not set because the daemon is started by process 1 (init), which is independent of user/graphical session, etc. A better way, conceivably, would be to query the system for active graphical sessions and determine their display variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the **write** command, which can be caught by KDE's **Write daemon**, and will be displayed in the Notification area in your KDE desktop.  The Write daemon is running by default; if not, you can change this in System settings -> System administration -> Startup and Shutdown -> Service manager.

By default the notification produces a sound, and a pop-up which lasts for about four seconds.  After that, you'll find a reminder of the notification on your taskbar.  You can manage the behaviour of this notification to some extent in System settings -> Common appearance and Behaviour -> Applications and System notifications -> Manage notifications -> Applications tab -> Event source: Local system message service.

Comment: I also found the **wall** command which seems more suitable. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try

```
echo hello > /dev/pts/0
```

Comment: That works for me in KDE Plasma on NixOS.